# jQuery function working only in debugger mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried to show and hide loader/spinner GIF while filtering row in a table (with 5000 rows).

```
$('.dropdown-filter-menu-item.select-all').click(function () {
     document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0].style.display='block';
    // filter function
    **code goes here**
   document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0].style.display='none';
})
```

Here, 'dropdown-filter-menu-item' is a class name of checkbox filter and modal is class name of 'loader' used.
When I placed a debugger in show or hide line it works fine. Without debugger, its not working.
I think the styles of element gets changed only after the function ends. Can you please help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you skipped important part of your code under `**code goes here**`. It is possible that your code is executed immediately, especially if the part of your code inside `**code goes here**` contains any async methods.

Comment: Can you set timeout

Answer (score 1):

> *I think the styles of element gets changed only after the function
>   ends*

Good guess, that's exactly what's happening, since the whole function is synchronous.

There's a nice trick that can be used, that will allow your loading image to show, and then tackle the time-consuming filtering function. Execute the filtering after a timeout :

```
$('.dropdown-filter-menu-item.select-all').click(function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0].style.display='block';
    setTimeout(filter); // defaults to 0ms
})

function filter() {
    **code goes here**
   document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0].style.display='none';
}
```

`setTimeout` allows your function to run in the next lifecycle, which allows the loading image to display first.

Comment: I am using library file for filtering. Refer : [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gdl). I added timeout function in "FilterMenu.prototype.selectAllUpdate", but I am facing the same issue.